# How to replace a page with another page in property sheet without clicking next button?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet which consists of three pages respectively.In the second page I placed a progress control ,here when the progress control reaches its final position ,it should automatically direct to the next page(final page) and what I did here is I had set this second page wizard button to CANCEL only(no NEXT or BACK is available).After the progress bar reaches it's final point then automatically the next page has to be appeared(Expected behavior).

Actually process is we have to press next button in order to navigate to the next page(usual behavior).As I did not enable any button excluding cancel button .I must be able to navigate to the next page once the progress control reaches it's maximum point automatically without any button press.

Can anyone please let me know whether there exists any way to do this.

Comment: When you say "replace" do you mean "move to another page"?

Comment: Yes absolutely "Moving to another page without any button click".In fact none of the button is enabled excluding Cancel button.

Comment: Have you tried using CPropertySheet::SetActivePage ()?  In a standard property sheet that will make a page active.

Answer (score 0):

Once the progress bar reaches the end, you can call [SetWizardButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex7e7b4s.aspx) to enable the Next button, followed by a call to [PressButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edy8fcx.aspx) to simulate the user clicking on the Next button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I was setting the progress bar in the OnInitDialog of the respective page .When I run the application I was able to see the liquid flowing very fast in the progress bar in seconds of time ,it should go a bit slow so that we can understand a flow of progress bar and as you mentioned SetWizardButtons ,I am setting that OnSetActive() method ,But when the page comes automatically the pages is getting displayed with those buttons active.Can you please let me know where and how to handle that progress bar and enabling of the wizard buttons on that progress bar  end status.

Comment: `OnInitDialog()` is fired only once for each property page, it is better to initialize your progress bar and disable the buttons in the `OnSetActive()` method; I suppose you set the values in the progress control based on a timer, so you would ned to call `SetWizardButtons()` followed by `PressButton()` when the progress reaches the end.